# java jlist doesn't display one of the items completely sometimes

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist

I am having problems with Jlist. I have ScrollPane and I added Jlist to it. Sometime I don't see the first item in the list.(I am seeing this behavior with other items in the list also)

I appreciate any help.

thanks,[image]

here is the code snippet

-JList creation:

```
    jAllScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    jAllScrollPane.getViewport().add(allNetLayer);
    allNetLayer.setVisibleRowCount(3);
```

- I add items to JList in the following method

  ```
   void addItemToList(String lay)
   {
          layerInit =1;
          if(lay.compareTo("All") ==0)
          {
               listData.clear();
          }
          if(lay.compareTo("DONE") == 0)
          {
               allLay.setListData(listData);
               jAllScrollPane.updateUI();
          }
          else
          {
               listData.addElement(lay);
          }
          layerInit =0;
    }
  ```
- GUI creation:

  ```
   javax.swing.GroupLayout jLogPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jLogPanel);
  jLogPanel.setLayout(jLogPanelLayout);
  jLogPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
              ....
              ....
              .addComponent(jAllScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 200, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE))
              ....
              ....
          .addContainerGap())
  );
       jLogPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
          ....
          ....
           .addComponent(jAllScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 190, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
           ....
           ....
          .addGap(20,20,20))))

  );
  jTabbedPane1.addTab("All", jLogPanel);
  ```

Comment: Where's your code? Or are we supposed to guess what you may be doing wrong?

Comment: @G G `1)` impove your Accept ratio, `2)` I think that this isn't possible to reply, `3)` don't use setBounds(), `4)` use proper LayoutManager, `5)` read Oracle tutorial about JList `6)` especially to read Oracle tutorial about JScrollPane `7)` even batteries in my magic globe are fully recharged, please to post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) generated a.m. output to the GUI

Answer (score 1):

Your posted code is very messed up. Also it's very difficult to compile it.

The only thing I can do for you is

- advice - read @mKorbel comment and take it to your heart
- use simpler to use layouts - `BorderLayout`, `GridLayout`, etc. or `MigLayout`
- use `fire*(data changed)` methods on Swing's models, repaint()
- you can use `new JScrollPane(<panel inside>)`
- `addItemToList` should have [single responsibility](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/curlys-law-do-one-thing.html) - add item to list - conditions shouldn't be there
- you shouldn't reset whole list model data to add one item
- you can do `import` - instead of writing every time `javax.swing.GroupLayout`
- you shouldn't create state when creating GUI - `layerInit`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using :

```
jAllScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
jAllScrollPane.getViewport().add(allNetLayer);
```

to add the Component, use the method [JScrollPane.html#setViewportView(java.awt.Component)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setViewportView%28java.awt.Component%29) (if you don't want to use the JScrollPane constructor that take a parameter).

> Applications that don't provide the view directly to the JScrollPane constructor should use this method to specify the scrollable child that's going to be displayed in the scrollpane.